Rust macro parsing arbitrary text
Consider that we have a large automatically generated file(s) of C-style definitions of the form:
// header.h

#define DEFINITION_1 0x12335
#define DEFINITION_2 0x4567566
#define DEFINITION_3 0x6666
//..................
#define DEFINITION_N 0x56657

Now, in my Rust program I am interested in having some very specific of these definitions to be embedded in different places/modules, such as
pub const DEF_2: SomeType = SomeType::new(0x4567566); // The value in the constructor is 
                                                      // corresponding the the definition 
                                                      // in the header 

It would be nice if there was some way to have a macro magic!() with a usage as follows:
pub const DEF_2: SomeType = SomeType::new(magic!("header.h", DEFINITION_2));

Now, I am aware of Bindgen, but it will indiscriminately generate all of definitions that are in allow-list or aren't blacklisted. These lists will have to be manually adjusted each time another definition is needed or removed, it will also dump it into a single file. While the magic! will only pull the required definition just in the place it is needed at. Is this something that is possible with the current state of Rust?

You can read files as part of a macro (though it pretty much has to be a procedural macro). Within that macro you can do whatever you want. Here's a Q&A for inspiration.

@kmdreko "Whatever you want" as long as it is in the 'build.rs' and spitting out artifacts that are compiled later. But I am talking about a macro that will expand into a compile-time constant. However, after I wrote the question I've got an idea to feed the header hole to Bindgen, and then write a proc macro on it's output since it will guarantee a proper 'TokenStream'

@EugeneSh. no, a proc macro can be arbitrary rust code and expand to anything you can come up with during it's execution, including arbitrary literals. that are arbitrary text from arbitrary files. It's not dependent on the existence of a build.rs in any way shape or form.

@cafce25 Is it? Then I need go back to docs.. Does it mean that if I have a 'no_std' cross-compiled code, I can embed proc macros depending on 'std' and running on the host at compile time?

Ahh.. looks like it would require a separate crate for the macros

Yep. Procedural macro is compiled for the host, so it must be a separate compilation unit, but it will be able to use everything available on host no matter what's the limitations of the target.
